# Board components that are sensitive to soldering heat

Tags: embedded, arm, production-testing

I have to test the various components of a board after manufacturing. I was told that SRAM, for example, is particularly sensitive to the soldering heat. What are other sensitive components?

The board comprises of an ARM Cortex M3, with USB, Ethernet, GPS, SPI Flash, PSRAM, SIM card and SD card.

Comment: Read the datasheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no obvious reason for SRAM to be more susceptible to heat than similar products.  If there IS a reason it will be covered in the data sheet.

The data sheets of ALL major components that are used in a quality product will provide heat sensitivity information.
 If this is volume production then you need to look at ALL data sheets for ALL factors that may be relevant to your testing.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen inductors melt and go faulty.

Any component which isn't kept completely dry can suffer when heated.

Answer (score 1):

its very rare that a soldering iron used properly will damage electronics.  I would suggest a few of the SparkFun soldering tutorials.
http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/36

heat ovens and heat guns on the other hand can definitely melt plastic housings on electronics.  For those I would check the datasheets.